# Can we assume cliches are known to all and stop repeating them ad nauseum?

Tags: discussion

Prhaps an FAQ section would help.

My pet peeves:

(1) There is no caste system - what we have is Varna/Guna  which is not by birth.

(2) There is nothing called HInduism - it is actually Sanatana Dharma.

(3) Hinduism is not a religion - its a way of life.

(4) "effulgence", "lotus feet", "puissance"

(5) Non-Hindus asking "why do Hindus put a mark on their forehead"?

Comment: They're definitely not "known" to all, because they're not even agreed on by all.  There's plenty of traditional Hindus (myself included) who believe that Varna is a birth-based system (which is a good thing once you consider reincarnation), and that Hinduism and Sanatana Dharma are synonymous (though the former is a term coined by outsiders).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: "Varna is birth based system" can be proven by vedas?? (Here birth means son born of kshatriya varna parents is kshatriya himself, son born of vaisha varna parents is vaishya varna himself)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan but tradition is not bigger than direct vedic reference.

Comment: @zaxebo1 It can be proven using scripture, but Meta is not the right place to discuss this.  It can be discussed in the main site or in chat rooms.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I'd probably disagree with your interpretation of those Vedic verses, but regardless the point is that this is a matter that different sects of Hinduism disagree about.

Comment: By the way, point number 2 in these survey answers I wrote a while back is relevant: http://gdurl.com/zlTF I was responding to these questions: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3409/36

Comment: We don't dictate people that something is true and something is false. We don't support caste system and at the same time, we are not against it. All the points you mentioned are your personal opinions. It is not allowed to dictate or force people that some idea is right and some idea is wrong.